# What is the purpose of template engines in Java?

Tags: javascript, java, html, spring-boot, backend

I'm an android developer and about two years and recently I've been thinking about building web applications. So I started researching about spring boot and everything is great. Then, I came across this thing called template engines (thymeleaf) which by definition separate your code from presentation.

What is confusing me is how can a backend server have html? should the presentation be handled by html, css and javascript in the front end? I even saw tutorials where they actually type in html code in their controller as return values.

My understanding is that the backend server exposes APIs for the frontend to use by using AJAX and the frontend will manipulate this data and present the information on the screen, why would a backend provide html code?

THank you

Comment: may be you wrongly tagged `javascript`, please edit.

Comment: did you read the post?

Comment: Not every app is a SPA - this site for example is not a SPA, html is rendered on the server in a templating engine rather than on the frontend. This has advantages and disadvantages

Answer (score 9):

> the frontend will manipulate this data

What front end? You mean the JavaScript code in the HTML page? Where did that come from? Oh yeah, **the server**.

It is the server that *serves* the HTML pages to the client, as well as any .js and .css files.

The server could provide static pages, and anything dynamic is handled by JavaScript. Or, the server could *dynamically* build the HTML page, using ... *you guessed it* ... a template engine.

You generally don't want JavaScript to build the page initially, just to use JavaScript for handling any dynamic behavior. Some pages don't even need any dynamic behavior.

Unless of course you're thinking about [single-page applications](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) (SPA), where there is only one root HTML page, and everything else is built client-side with JavaScript and AJAX calls, but most web applications are not SPAs.

Answer (score 2):

I know this question has been answered pretty effectively so far, but I want to add my two cents in as I work with Thymeleaf often.

The easiest way to think about a template engine is that it allows some dynamic development of html based on information passed to it by the controller method. This allows you to put logic in that normally wouldn't exist, or say display a certain section if a user is perhaps logged into admin.

If web pages were houses, html is the frame, css is the walls, Javascript is the lights and electricity, and a template engine would pretty much just be the architect designing the plans on the fly before the frame was built based on desires of the buyer of the house (user inputs).

Answer (score 1):

Thymeleaf replaces JSP by providing HTML pages using a template engine. The controller requests the HTML file and Spring Boot provides that template after building it using the Model provided.

[Thymeleaf](https://www.baeldung.com/thymeleaf-in-spring-mvc) is great because it allows you to rebuild templates on the fly. Lets say for example you're showing a users points to them on the front end, but maybe the points increase or decrease.

What you can do is build the template in the background using a Model. The Model reference is *[magically](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html)* provided to the template provided which parses it.

```java
@RequestMapping(...)
public String request(Model model) {
    model.put("points", 5);
    return "my-template.html"
}
```

Then use the Thymeleaf language to provide your object to the HTML file to be processed in the engine during runtime.

```html
<html..>
    <head>...</head>

    <body>
    <h1 th:text="${points}"></h1>
</html>
```

Spring Boots Template engine will build this in the background and present it to the user, but it will show the actual points to the end user! Hope this helps a tiny bit.

Answer (score 0):

OK, newer Apps and websites may just load/boot/open once and then pull or push data via AJAX requests, this is good, it saves traffic and it is fast.

But it has not always been like this and some Frameworks still don't build everything on small requests. Spring in Java or Symfony in PHP are MVC Frameworks and use template engines to build pages. This may sound a little outdated but there is still a lot of websites using this.

And if you build a web app for a customer with slow PCs or other devices and the page contents are performance heavy you might want to do as much work as possible on the server so that the user does not have to wait for long. And also you can cache the rendered pages. There is even server side rendering of react pages to e.g. make the initial page load faster...

With Java and Spring I did just use JSP I don't know thymeleaf. Just use what you like and maybe what is most supported/documented.

And building websites like this does not mean you cannot use AJAX, but if you use templates you need to think about what makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

> What is confusing me is how can a backend server have html?

The "back end" *must* have HTML, because that's what's delivered to, and rendered by, the client.

It may just be that the back end "server" is just a CDN delivering, say, an HTML/JS SPA, but there's still *something* delivering content to the browser.

That said: server-side rendering is still a thing, and has had a resurgence lately--a React app may have its initial rendering done on the server so again the client gets a page rendered with both HTML and associated data, and *then* starts acting like a normal SPA.

> My understanding is that the backend server exposes APIs for the frontend to use by using AJAX and the frontend will manipulate this data and present the information on the screen, why would a backend provide html code?

Because something needs to run the JS to access those APIs.

Some history:

Browsers used to suck. JS used to be a neat add-on, sites were relatively static, and essentially all rendering was done on the server. The back end would get data from wherever it got data from and generate complete HTML pages, and there was little happening on the client side other than some form fields, maybe some validation, and that was about the extent of it.

Comment: I see, but with html css javascript in the front end, why bother to have the backend sending html? My understanding in the front end ask backend for data specific information, it is up to the front on how the data is rendered on the screen

Comment: Where else would it come from? HTML isn't on the client until it comes from somewhere, regardless of what's in that HTML. *You* might think that all apps just make API calls and doing all the rendering, but that's not how the web started. All this client application stuff is relatively new. And, as I said, SSR is back anyway, even if it's just for the first load.